# Converting a Dictionary with a hierarchical structure into a List

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, dictionary, collections

I have a basic dictionary object with a hierarchical structure, in which the KEY is the child and the PAIR is its parent.

Here is sample data for key value pairs in the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string,string> elements;

("Cell", "Cells")
("Cells", "Tissue")
("Tissue", "Organ")
("Organ", "System")
("System", "Body")
```

I want to convert this Dictionary into a `List<string>`, maintaining the hierarchical order of elements. So, the output would look like this:

```
"Cell",
"Cells",
"Tissue",
"Organ",
"System", 
"Body"
```

How can do this? Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we can find the first key by checking that such key doesn't exist in values collection inside dictionary. Then we can add it to `List` and add all other keys by accessing values in our dictionary using last key from our `List` collection (this helps us keep the correct order) :

```
        Dictionary<string, string> elements = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"Tissue", "Organ"},
            {"Cell", "Cells"},
            {"System", "Body"},
            {"Cells", "Tissue"},
            {"Organ", "System"},
        };

        List<string> hierarchy = new List<string>();

        hierarchy.Add(elements.Keys.First(el => !elements.ContainsValue(el)));

        while(elements.ContainsKey(hierarchy.Last()))
            hierarchy.Add(elements[hierarchy.Last()]);

        foreach (var item in hierarchy)
            Console.Write(item + ",  ");

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
Cell, Cells, Tissue, Organ, System,  Body,
```